# Python. функция работы с процентами

Tags: python

Есть ли в стандартной библиотеке python метод **вычисления процентов** ?
Или в подключаемом модуле.

Нужно сделать такую функцию, чтобы с введенной юзером цифры отнималось 10%, и выдавалась конечная цифра без этих 10%.

Comment: Так а чем умножение на 0.9 не устраивает?

    0.9 * X = 1 * X - 0.1 * X

Т.е. 1 * X -> 100% от X, 0.1 * X -> 10% от X, 0.9 * X -> 90% от X

Comment: хотя да, устраивает. рассчитывал, что есть какая-нить волшебный метод в math.

Comment: Если мне не изменяет память, проценты проходят в пятом классе средней школы. А еще тут должна быть фраза про то, нужна ли программисту математика

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Для начала выясните, что Вы хотите получить.

Пользователь вводит 100%, а Вы хотите увидеть 90%? Тогда это X/100*90 = X * 0.9

Пользователь вводит 110%, а Вы хотите увидеть 100%? Тогда это X/110*100

Если идти от того, что на калькуляторах происходит:

"438 - 10%" по факту означает "438 минус 10% от 438"

Будет так: 438 - (438 / 100 * 10) = 438 - 0.1 * 438 = 438 - 43.8 = 394.2

Comment: да. все правильно. софта - молодец. на печеньку!

Answer (score 0):

```
x = float(input('Введите цифры : '))
y = 0.1
z = x - (x * y)
print(round(z,2))
```

Функцию 'round', ее значения можете поменять для какой точности вам нужно.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]